# change values of array items between 2 given coordinates

Tags: python

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]

def connect_nodes(node1, node2):
    y_distance = node2[0] - node1[0]
    x_distance = node2[1] - node1[1]

    print('distance between', node1, "and", node2, "is", y_distance, "on Y-axis and", x_distance, "on X-axis")

    if y_distance == 0:
        if x_distance > 0:
            for i in range(node1[1]+1, node1[1]+x_distance, 1):
                matrix[node1[0]][i] = 0
        if x_distance < 0:
            for i in range(node1[1]+x_distance+1, node1[1], 1):
                matrix[node1[0]][i] = 0

    if x_distance == 0:
        if y_distance > 0:
            for i in range(node1[0]+1, node1[0]+y_distance, 1):
                matrix[i][node1[1]] = 0
        if y_distance < 0:
            for i in range(node1[0]+y_distance+1, node1[0], 1):
                matrix[i][node1[1]] = 0

connect_nodes([1,0], [1,5])
connect_nodes([1,5], [5,5])

for m in matrix:
    print(m)
```

I get two coordinates which are two items of a 2D-array. Then I need to draw some kind of a line between 2 given coordinates - edit values of items on a particular row or column. Above is some code I wrote to solve this problem. But I'd like to know is there more elegant way to do the same?
P.S. What if the coordinates are not on the same line (vertical or horizontal)? How do I draw a line between [1,1] and [9,3] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PIL for that:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])

# Load matrix into image
im = Image.fromarray(matrix, mode='I')

# Draw line from (1,1) to (9,3) with color 0
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.line((1, 1, 9,3), fill=0)
```

Convert back to numpy array:

```
np.array(im)

>>> array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Note that the coordinates are 0-indexed, so the top-left corner is `(0,0)`.

Read more:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageDraw.html